# QML Transition causes to set property multiple times, where is source of this bad behaviour?

Tags: qml, state, qtquick2

I have a Browser and Player (each in a Loader) in a Row. I want whenever user clicked on a media from the Browser, the Player is loaded and displayed.
So I used states as below:

```
            ╔═>>>╣middle state: load player╠>>>══╗  
            ║                                    ║
            ╩                                    ╩
first state: display browser         second state: display player
            ╦                                    ╦
            ║                                    ║
            ╚═<<<╣middle state: load browser╠<<<═╝
```

in the middle states, user waits for loader to loads related custom item. Then state will be changed to target state.
You can see qml codes below:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
    id: root
    signal back()

    Row {
        id: row
        height: parent.height
        Loader {
            id: videoBrowserLoader
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            asynchronous: true
            active: false
            focus: active
            onStatusChanged: {}
            sourceComponent: videoBrowserComponent
            onActiveChanged: console.log("Browser Loader is active:"+active)
        }
        Loader {
            id: videoPlayerLoader
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            asynchronous: true
            active: false
            focus: active
            onStatusChanged: {}
            sourceComponent: videoPlayerComponent
            onActiveChanged: console.log("Player Loader is active:"+active)
        }
        states: [
            State {
                name: "start"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: true
                    asynchronous: false
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: false
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: row
                    x: 0
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "browser"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: true
                    asynchronous: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: false
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: row
                    x: 0
                }
            },
            /*State {
                extend: row.oldState
                name: "middleState"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: true
                    asynchronous: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: true
                }
            },*/
            State {
                name: "middleState_browserToPlayer"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: true
                    asynchronous: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: row
                    x: 0
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "player"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: false
                    asynchronous: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: row
                    x: -root.width
                }
            },
            State {
                name: "middleState_playerToBrowser"
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoBrowserLoader
                    active: true
                    asynchronous: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: videoPlayerLoader
                    active: true
                }
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: row
                    x: -root.width
                }
            }
        ]
        property string oldState: ""
        state: "start"
        onStateChanged: console.log("$$$$State: "+state)
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                id: problematicTransition
                from: "middleState_browserToPlayer"
                to: "player"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: row; property: "x"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint }
                    PropertyAction { target: videoBrowserLoader; property: "active" }
                    ScriptAction { script: console.log("%%%%FINISHED"); }
                }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "middleState_playerToBrowser"
                to: "browser"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: row; property: "x"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint }
                    PropertyAction { target: videoPlayerLoader; property: "active" }
                    ScriptAction { script: console.log("%%%%FINISHED"); }
                }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "middleState"
                to: "player"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: row; property: "x"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint }
                    PropertyAction { target: videoBrowserLoader; property: "active" }
                }
            },
            Transition {
                from: "middleState"
                to: "browser"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { target: row; property: "x"; duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuint }
                    PropertyAction { target: videoPlayerLoader; property: "active" }
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    Component {
        id: videoPlayerComponent
        VideoPlayer {
            id: videoPlayer
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            visible: true
            onBack: { /*row.oldState = row.state; row.state = "middleState";*/row.state = "middleState_playerToBrowser"; }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                videoPlayer.focus = true;
                console.log("####MAKE PLAYER ON");
                row.state = "player";
            }
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: videoBrowserComponent
        VideoBrowser {
            id: videoBrowser
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            visible: true
            onBack: { root.back(); }
            onOpenMedia: { /*row.oldState = row.state; row.state = "middleState";*/row.state = "middleState_browserToPlayer" /*mediaController.openMedia(url);*/ }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                videoBrowser.focus = true;
                console.log("####MAKE BROWSER ON");
                row.state = "browser" ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code, out put will be as below:

```
qml: $$$$State: middleState_browserToPlayer
qml: Player Loader is active:true
qml: ####MAKE PLAYER ON
qml: $$$$State: player
qml: Browser Loader is active:false
qml: Browser Loader is active:true
qml: ####MAKE BROWSER ON
qml: $$$$State: browser
qml: Player Loader is active:false
```

As you can see, **(THE PROBLEM) Browser loader unloaded and loaded again immediately in lines 5 and 6 in output.**
If I remove Transition `id: problematicTransition` output will be as below:

```
qml: $$$$State: middleState_browserToPlayer
qml: Player Loader is active:true
qml: ####MAKE PLAYER ON
qml: $$$$State: player
qml: Browser Loader is active:false
qml: $$$$State: middleState_playerToBrowser
qml: Browser Loader is active:true
```

and in backward from the Player to the Browser, following output will be generated:

```
qml: ####MAKE BROWSER ON
qml: $$$$State: browser
qml: Player Loader is active:false
qml: %%%%FINISHED
```

as you can see, in backward from the Player to the Browser there is not any problem and works as expected.
Is there any mistake in my code? Is this a bug?